# Why won't my code to detect ctrl key state work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, internet-explorer-9, keypress

I'm trying to open new window if <kbd>shift</kbd> is pressed when the user clicks <kbd>enter</kbd>, and a new tab if they hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. The <kbd>shift</kbd> part works but the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> part doesn't...

```
var ctrlPressed = false;
var shiftPressed = false;
var stb = null;
function onload() {
stb = document.getElementById("searchTextBox");
}
    function enter(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if (!ctrlPressed && !shiftPressed) {
            window.location = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + encodeURI(stb.value) + "&fr2=sb-top&fr=404_web&pqstr=" + encodeURI(stb.value);
            }
            else if (ctrlPressed) {
            window.open("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + encodeURI(stb.value) + "&fr2=sb-top&fr=404_web&pqstr=" + encodeURI(stb.value));
            }
            else if (shiftPressed) {
            window.open("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + encodeURI(stb.value) + "&fr2=sb-top&fr=404_web&pqstr=" + encodeURI(stb.value), "_blank");
            }
        }
    }
    function searchdown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 17) {
            ctrlPressed = true;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            shiftPressed = true;
        }
    }
    function searchup(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 17) {
            ctrlPressed = false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            shiftPressed = false;
        }
    }
```

Also I can't use jQuery...

Comment: where is your event delegation?

Answer (score 2):

Did you know about [event.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) which tells you if the control key is held down?